# How to serve React

Tags: reactjs, go, mux

I have a simple React application I would like to serve from my Go server back end. I hear the process is similar to serving a static html file, but I just can't seem to get it to work.

When I try to view the app on the browser it says "This page isn't working" and that "localhost has redirected too many times"

Here is the code where I am running the server locally as well as trying to handle the react application

```
func main() {

r := mux.NewRouter()

// handle app
buildHandler := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./client/build/index.html"))
r.PathPrefix("/").Handler(buildHandler)

staticHandler := http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./client/build/static")))
r.PathPrefix("/static/").Handler(staticHandler)

r.HandleFunc("/", index).Methods("GET")

srv := &http.Server{
    Handler:      r,
    Addr:         "127.0.0.1:8080",
    WriteTimeout: 15 * time.Second,
    ReadTimeout:  15 * time.Second,
}

// serve
fmt.Println("Server started on PORT 8080")
log.Fatal(srv.ListenAndServe())


}
```

Here is the code for the index route

```
func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // not sure if this is necessary
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "index.html")
}
```

I believe the solution is simple and that I am most likely making a small error somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case only build handler is needed. It must point to directory not a file. Rest of the handlers are obsolete except the case of routing.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    r := mux.NewRouter()

    r.HandleFunc("/route1", index).Methods("GET")
    r.HandleFunc("/route2", index).Methods("GET")
    buildHandler := http.FileServer(http.Dir("client/build"))
    r.PathPrefix("/").Handler(buildHandler)

    srv := &http.Server{
        Handler:      r,
        Addr:         "127.0.0.1:8080",
        WriteTimeout: 15 * time.Second,
        ReadTimeout:  15 * time.Second,
    }

    fmt.Println("Server started on PORT 8080")
    log.Fatal(srv.ListenAndServe())

}

func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "client/build/index.html")
}
```

The same can be achieved with the standard library only.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    r := http.NewServeMux()

    r.HandleFunc("/route1", index)
    r.HandleFunc("/route2", index)
    buildHandler := http.FileServer(http.Dir("client/build"))
    r.Handle("/", buildHandler)

    srv := &http.Server{
        Handler:      r,
        Addr:         "127.0.0.1:8080",
        WriteTimeout: 15 * time.Second,
        ReadTimeout:  15 * time.Second,
    }

    fmt.Println("Server started on PORT 8080")
    log.Fatal(srv.ListenAndServe())

}

func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "client/build/index.html")
}
```

Comment: I improved my answer to handle additional routes.