# How to serve Angular app from Go HTTP Server?

Tags: angular, go

I'm trying to serve an Angular application (Angular 8.2.14) from a server written in Go.

Searching around I found the following snippet that supposedly makes the trick.

```
func main() {
    http.ListenAndServe(":4000", http.FileServer(http.Dir(folderDist)))
}
```

Where **folderDist** is the directory where I made **ng build** of my application.

When I navigate to localhost:4000 in my examples, I receive on the browser the following errors:

```
runtime-es2015.js:1 Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
styles-es2015.js:1 Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
main-es2015.js:1 Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
polyfills-es2015.js:1 Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
vendor-es2015.js:1 Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

What am I missing?

I've tried the solution [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58088803/how-to-serve-react), but the errors are still the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to serve React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58088803/how-to-serve-react) It is the same for Vue, React or Angular.

Comment: @GrzegorzŻur same results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/39520045/13860

Comment: @Flimzy No. As answered below, it's an Angular bug, Thanks anyway for your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

Apparently there is a bug in some versions of Angular 8...

Edit **tsconfig.json** file and changes the line "target" to "es5".

```
"target": "es5",
```

Make "ng build".

Done!